# Got stuck in a htaccess and rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my first question here, so thank you all in advance and also sorry for my bad english.

I'm trying to apply htaccess and rewrites to one project I'm worknig on, but the problem is that I'd never done this before. I've been reading a lot of post (like http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php or this one http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/rewrite/1/#.UW7mHqJhXCd) and articles about this, but combined with no previous experience on regular expressions I can't get it done...

I've been with this for 2 days now and I'm running out of time to finnish it, so I was wondering if someone could give me a hand, so here it goes:

---

WHAT I HAVE:

3 files at my root:
index.php
home.php
404.php

On the database:
On the users table there is a field called user_url

HOW NEED THIS TO WORK:

I want to display every user personal page like this www.example.com/user_url

I'm doing it like this at the moment www.example.com/?id=user_url

But I also need this to be able to go directly to the files in some cases, like with home.php instead of having to make something like ?id=home

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above ones that do other kinds of routing:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

As far as this:

> But I also need this to be able to go directly to the files in some cases, like with home.php instead of having to make something like ?id=home

I have no idea what you're talking about. If you mean you'd like to go to `http://www.example.com/home.php` without it getting rewritten to `/index.php?id=home.php`, then that's what the 2 conditions above do.

Comment: I think `index.php` can be removed from there?

Comment: @Nathan it can, it just means one extra cycle through the URL-file mapping processing pipeline, but it's hardly noticeable.

Comment: It works prefectly! Thank you so much, you really saved me a lot of trouble!

The only thing is that it didn't work for index until I removed "/" from "/index.php?id=$1"